# "geographically organized" information or "organized geographical" information?

Tags: grammar, word-order

> Pointing at his new designed map, Tom proudly said that it was not a piece of paper, but a record of ____________.
>
> A. organized geographically information
> B. geographical organized information
> C. geographically organized information
> D. organized geographical information

The answer is C. But D i think is also right,for the two adjectives modify "information".

Comment: You're quite right, and as usual, such online tests aren't worth the metaphorical paper they're written on. Note that D carries a slightly different nuance than C, because the implication is that the referent in D is *primarily* "geographical" data (height above sea level with associated grid references, or whatever), whereas in C it's just "any old data" capable of being organised geographically (the results of a survey of eating habits with associated postcodes, perhaps). The difference is between whether "geographical[ly]" modifies "information" or "organized".

Comment: Personally, I'm sceptical that *any* native Anglophone would ever come up with that example context: *Pointing at his **new designed map,** Tom said...* In all the tens of millions of books indexed by Google, the sequence ***new designed map*** [*doesn't appear even once.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22new+designed+map%22)

Comment: Could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired.

Comment: Where did you find this question?  It appears to contain a grammatical error.  "new designed map" is incorrect.  It should be a "newly designed map".

Comment: @Billy Kerr Emm,"new" can be adv too,referring [item](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/new) in MW dictionary.

Comment: @WingTiger - yes as in new book or a new car, but not with "new designed [something]". It's not right. It sounds like a non-native English speaker wrote this, and is distinctly odd.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both C and D are grammatically correct, but they have different meanings.

C means the information is organized according to geography, and is probably the intended meaning.

D means the information is geographical, and it's organized somehow, but it doesn't specify how the information is organized.

Comment: In other words, in D both adjectives modify the noun ‘information’ — but in C ‘geographically’ modifies ‘organized’, and the _combination_ modifies ‘information’. Since there's little point mentioning that the map is merely organised (as it's unlikely to be more so than any other map), C seems most likely to be the intended meaning: that the organisation is geographical.